# Групповое кодирование (алгоритм сжатия)

Tags: алгоритм, терминология, сжатие

"Групповое кодирование" (алгоритм сжатия) - это алгоритм RLE? Или есть еще какие-то?

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Base RLE encode python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/595126/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Групповое кодирование – это русский термин для Run Length Encoding (RLE) алгоритма – [Кодирование длин серий](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9).