# Для чего в Python 3.8 вводят новый оператор :=?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[PEP 572 - Assignment Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) вводит новый оператор `:=`.

Что он делает? Для чего он нужен?

Comment: Вы же и ответ напишете? )

Comment: по-моему в описании данного PEP есть [шикарные и понятные примеры](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics). +1 за то что обратили внимание на такую полезную "фичу" - ждём Python 3.8 ... ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000198/what-does-colon-equal-in-python-mean

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я бы предпочёл чтобы кто-то более опытный и мудрый это сделал :)

Comment: @nick_gabpe многие более опытные люди могут привести аргументы почему не нужно вводить `:=`. [Guido не зря в бессрочный отпуск собрался](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-committers/2018-July/005664.html)

Comment: «Вот почему нужно использовать оператор := в Python» https://habr.com/ru/company/skillfactory/blog/683418/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Примеры из существующего (не специально придуманного) кода (grep-нул по диску), к которому можно [PEP 572: The Walrus Operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#abstract) применить:

- *копирование файлов* (и аналогичный код для сокетов и других объектов, из которых можно данные принимать пока не пусто):

  ```
  # copy the rest
  buf = inputfile.read(bufsize)
  while buf:
      outputfile.write(buf)
      buf = inputfile.read(bufsize)
  ```

  с [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#abstract) можно заменить на::

  ```
  # copy the rest
  while buf := inputfile.read(bufsize):
      outputfile.write(buf)
  ```

  что, конечно, и сейчас можно записать как:

  ```
  # copy the rest
  shutil.copyfileobj(inputfile, outputfile, bufsize)
  ```
- копирование, где `shutil.copyfileobj()` нельзя напрямую применить (см. [Get an audio file with HTTP GET and then play it in python 3. TTS in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33320218/4279)):

  ```
  while True:
      data = wavfile.readframes(4096)
      if not data:
          break
      output_file.write(data)
  ```

  с [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#abstract) можно заменить на:

  ```
  while data := wavfile.readframes(4096):
      output_file.write(data)
  ```

  иногда это пишут через `iter()` c двумя аргументами (см. [Floating point to 16 bit Twos Complement Binary, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31464022/4279)):

  ```
  output_file.writelines(iter(lambda: wavfile.readframes(4096), b''))
  ```
- *ветвление с регулярными выражениями*, к примеру, код из [Python 3 get song name from internet radio stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35102278/4279):

  ```
  m = re.search(r"StreamTitle='([^']*)';", metadata)
  if m:
      title = m.group(1)
      if title:
          break  # found title
  ```

  можно заменить на:

  ```
  if m := re.search(r"StreamTitle='([^']*)';", metadata) and title := m.group(1):
      break  # found title
  ```
- *списковое включение* (listcomp), где какое-то выражение несколько раз используется. К примеру, чтобы напечатать публичные неспециальные свойства объекта `obj` (атрибуты-не методы) как словарь, созданный dictcomp:

  ```
  pprint({name: attr
          for name in dir(obj) if not name.startswith("__")
          for attr in [getattr(obj, name)] if not callable(attr)})
  ```

  здесь [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) реализуется с помощью: `for attr in [getattr(obj, name)]` идиомы (добавляется лишний вложенный цикл по списку из одного элемента). C [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#abstract) это можно переписать как:

  ```
  pprint({name: attr
          for name in dir(obj)
          if not name.startswith("__") and not callable(attr := getattr(obj, name))})
  ```

  Конечно, особенно в тех случаях когда целое выражение не нужно, можно явный цикл использовать вместо dictcomp.

  Ещё пример listcomp (см. [Base RLE encode python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/595126/23044)):

  ```
  def rle_groupby(text):
      return ''.join([char if count == 1 else str(count) + char
                      for char, same in groupby(text)
                      for count in [sum(1 for _ in same)]])
  ```

  здесь та же DRY идиома используется со списком из одного элемента. C [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#abstract) это можно переписать как:

  ```
  def rle_groupby(text):
      return ''.join([char if (count := sum(1 for _ in same)) == 1 else str(count) + char
                      for char, same in groupby(text)])
  ```

[Примеры существующего кода и улучшенных вариантов из самой PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#examples).

> **Q:** Почему нельзя использовать обычный оператор =, как в C#?

**A:** Чтобы не было путаницы с `==` как в Си [между `if (x == y)` и `if (x = y)`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#why-not-just-turn-existing-assignment-into-an-expression), которые кардинально разные вещи делают.

Comment: Почему нельзя использовать обычный оператор `=`, как в C#?

Comment: @Alex78191 обновил ответ

Comment: На самом деле все эти "примеры" хоть и встречаются в реальной жизни, просто неправильно написаны. Каждый из них можно написать лучше и питонячей...

Comment: @AndrioSkur жду с нетерпением ваших "лучших" примеров (или хотя бы просто для сравнения). Я могу обновить ответ или вы свой  можете опубликовать. Не забудьте слово "неправильно" обосновать.

Comment: @AndrioSkur что ж вы такие громкие заявления "неправильно написаны" делаете, а как вас обосновать попросили, показать что вы считаете "лучше", так сразу молчание, в кусты спрятались.

Comment: @jfs я не спрятался) Мне банально лень писать примеры. Над ними думать сначала надо. А мне между прочим очень тяжело думать

Comment: @AndrioSkur talk is cheap, show us the code

Comment: Подробно и доступно.

Answer (score 16):

Он не нужен - это так называемый *синтаксический сахар*, который позволяет писать код более компактно и более понятно.

Вот пример без синтаксического сахара:

```
if len(string) > 100:
    print(len(string))             # дважды вычисляется len(string)
```

То же самое:

```
if (length := len(string)) > 100:
    print(length)
```

Другой пример:

```
age = int(input("Ваш возраст: "))
if age > 18:                        # age должен быть введен перед if
    print(age)
```

может выть

```
if (age := int(input("Ваш возраст: "))) > 18:
    print(age)
```

**Примечание:** Программисты на *C/C++* это знают и используют *с первых версий этих языков*. В *Питоне* это будет возможно *от версии 3.8*.

Comment: В C++ нельзя было совмещать инициализацию и сравнение https://stackoverflow.com/a/7837092

Comment: @Alex78191, здесь речь не идет об инициализации (т.к. в Питоне нет деклараций). Сравнение с C/C++ только об присваивании прямо в выражениях, хорошо знакомое из *Керниган, Ритчи: Язык программирования Си* (`while ((c = getchar()) != EOF`). Но ваш комментарий безусловно интересный для программистов в C++. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, я ошибся, не инициализация, а объявление.