# Как упросить конструкцию

Tags: python

Дано задание упросить конструкцию до 1 строки кода

```
with open('text.txt', 'a') as f:
    i = ' '
    while True:
        i = input()
        f.write(i + '\n')
        if i == '':
            break
```

У меня вышло упростить лишь до 2 строк кода

```
i = ' '
while bool(i): i = input(); open('text.txt', 'a').write(f'{i}\n')
```

Comment: map() используйте и for для него.

Comment: Но для map нужно определённое количество итераций, а тут соблюдение условия

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while s := input():print(s, file=open('test.txt', 'a'))
```

либо так:

```
print(*iter(input, ''), sep='\n', file=open('test.txt', 'a'))
```

Если в `iter` передать два аргумента, то он будет вызывать первый аргумент (`input`), до тех пор, пока результат не будет равен второму аргументу (`''`)

Comment: Это работает но, можете объяснять как это работает. Например что это за конструкция := и как у нас записывается в файл значение и зачем нам в принципе что то выводить

Comment: @assert https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/854267/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-python-3-8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80. в `print` я передаю ещё одно значение, файл в который все это будет записываться

Answer (score 3):

спасибо [@Danis](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1374419/457260), что напомнил про возможности функции `iter`

```
open('text.txt', 'a').write('\n'.join(iter(input, '')))
```